# How to build apk package from C++ sources in command line for a service app

Tags: android, c++, build, apk

I have a C++ app that have no UI and provides a web service.

I would like to build it using NDK into a multiplatform .apk file. Since I have a Makefile for my build system, it sounds reasonable to build the .apk using command line too (to keep my automated build).

I've seen many examples on how to build .apk in command line from Java sources, but not found any example about C++ sources (may be because it is arch dependant).

As for the service nature of my app, is there something special to do to make it run in background?

Comment: The NDK isn't for building standalone apps but for shared libraries to be called from Java.  So you need to be building a shared library either as a `NativeActivity` (which is called from the Java platform) or as a complete Java application with a C++ shared library.  See [NativeActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NativeActivity) and/or [NDK](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/) .  Once you have decided on your architecture there are command line tools that you can integrate into your Makefile.

Comment: @RichardCritten Do you mean that making standalone apps with NDK is not good? My app perfectly run on Android. Why can't I use it directly without making a library from it? I don't see any benefit in Java in my case as anyway I need to build my code for many platforms using NDK.